# Web Scraping Python : how to show the body of the table?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table in this link: https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/facts/passenger-statistics.html?d=20230830
And when I check the # of tables, it only shows one. But when I do extract it, it only shows the Table headers.

Please help. Im still new in this :)

How do I scrape the table if in "View source" of the html it does not show the data?

```
import pandas as pd
# pip install openpyxl
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/facts/passenger-statistics.html?d=20230830'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

PAXtable = soup.find('table',class_ = 'tinymce-table1 table-passengerTrafficStat')
print(PAXtable)

for PAX in PAXtable.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = team.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        CP = row.find('td', id_='passengerTrafficStat').text.strip
        print(CP)
```

Comment: `requests` only gives you the source HTML. Try [`selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) or [`pyppeteer`](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) to interact with the browser.

Comment: if you just want the data, try getting the csv from 
https://www.immd.gov.hk/opendata/eng/transport/immigration_clearance/statistics_on_daily_passenger_traffic.csv